# Setting up a udp connection on android

Tags: android, udp

I'm trying to set up a simple udp connection on android studio (using java). I've created a new seperate thread to establish and listen to the connection but i keep getting a permission denied error:

[image]

this is the code im using for the connection:

```
public class ClientListen implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            DatagramSocket udpsocket = new DatagramSocket(14552, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 14552);
            udpsocket.send(packet);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("UDP: ", "Socket Error: ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("UDP Send: ", "IO Error", e);
        }

        boolean run = true;

        while (run) {
            try {
                DatagramSocket udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(14552, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
                byte[] message = new byte[1500];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
                Log.i("UDP Client: ", "about to wait to receive");
                udpSocket.receive(packet);
                String text = new String(message, 0, packet.getLength());
                Log.d("Recieved data ", text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("UDP Client ", "has IO Exception, error: ", e);
                run = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then im linking it in the main activity file as a new thread:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(new ClientListen()).start();
    }
}
```

I've never set up a udp port on android so im really confused on how to fix this error because i cant run it in admin or anything. is this an error with my code? or is it an issue with the port im trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

Have added all the related network permissions in the manifest?

try to add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I'll try adding it in but i thought udp's don't use internet connection? because my device is currently not connected to the internet

Comment: either you use localhost or network IP you are accessing the internet.

Comment: this ended up fixing my problem, thank you.